# centerHorizontal does not centre the image correctly

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:background="@drawable/bg"
        >
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" //CENTER 01
                >
            <!--center button-->
            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/img"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" //CENTER 02
                    />
        //...            
        </RelativeLayout>        
    </LinearLayout>
    <include android:id="@+id/banner" layout="@layout/banner"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The center button is centered, but not in the real center of the screen, but rather approx 50px to the right of the center. If I remove `centerHorizontal` CENTER01, then this does not happen.

Does anyone know why is this happening?

Comment: Wait, so it works fine when CENTER01 is removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue may be due to using of both Relative Layout and Linear Layout inside a xml file.

Change all **Linear Layout** to ***Relative Layouts*** so that Image View will be centered as you expected.

I too mingled both Linear Layout and Relative Layout in single XML and faces this kind of issue. Once i replaces all Linear Layout to Relative Layout my problem Resolved.

Try it.Thanks.Venky

Answer (score 3):

Please try  for `//CENTER 02`:

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

When you set `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` on a parent, it influences the behaviour of its children. Hence, your `ImageView` gets effected, creating the effect you see after already being placed in the center by other properties.

You can see this effect for yourself by placing a `TextView` in there with `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`.

Answer (score 1):

Its because in Relative Layout center_horizontal isn't the command. that works for views wrapped in linear Layout. for RelativeLayout you need to use

`android:layout_centerInParent="true";`

as the center gravity command in linear

or

```
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

as the gravity center_horizontal in linear.